# list index out of range - split() function in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, split, webproxy

I create a web proxy server and try to parse the url from the header but I get a problem with split()

```
def proxy_thread(connectionSocket,addr):

    request = connectionSocket.recv(Buffer)

    GETREQ = request.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').split('\r\n')[0]

    print ("Test " + GETREQ)

    url = GETREQ.split(" ")[1]
```

Here is the Traceback:
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dangt\Desktop\cheg.py", line 62, in proxy_thread
    url = GETREQ.split(" ")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: could you give what is in GETREQ?

Comment: "List index out of range" for index [1] clearly indicates your list contains only 1 element. Try debugging whether `GETREQ` contains any `" "` or not.

Comment: This is what is in GETREQ "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1" it has 3 elements. I can print out url. it is "www.google.com:443" but it still has Error: list index out of range